# Update query executing but not updating table with hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, sql-update

I have a db with 5 pieces (id, question, result) and i want to change my db with update query and hibernate.

I tried this

```
public void update()
    {
        try
        {
            Session session = getSession();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();                

            Query query = getSession().createQuery("update Nodes set question = 'test updating' where id = 1" );

            tx.commit();
            session.close();
```

I don't have error, in console i have

```
Infos: Hibernate: update node set question='test updating' where id=1
```

Hibernate execute my update without error but there is not in my db, why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public void update()
{
    try
    {
        Session session = getSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();                

        Query query = getSession().createQuery("update Nodes set question = 'test updating' where id = 1" );

        query.executeUpdate(); //add this line
        session.commit();
        session.close();
```

hope this helps you with your problem

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my update is not update in my db. thanks

Comment: no sorry, i haven't error but its no updating in db

Comment: you can try int results=qry.executeUpdate() and printing "results" and chek value is it really updating or not. If its 1 that means code is updating but not recording in your database. If its 0, that means no problem with ur db, its your query

Comment: I tested, result is equals to "1"

Comment: then your problem is might with commiting, try session.commit() instead of tx.commit();

Comment: i tested it but i haven't commit with session. thanks

Comment: use session.createQuery() instead of getSession().createQuery().

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    public void update()
    {
        try
        {
            Session session = getSession();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();                

            Query query = session.createQuery("update Nodes set question = 'test updating' where id = 1" );

            query.executeUpdate(); //add this line
            tx.commit();
            session.close();
    }

}
```

Hope this will help you.